# Minix 3: add new command

Tags: c, makefile, command, minix

I'm currently trying to add a new command to Minix. I want to add a command named `smile`, which I want to display continuously a smiling face `:-)`the same way the command `yes` do with `y`.

I already created the `smile` dir in src/commands, with smile.c and Makefile, and added `smile` to src/commands/Makefile.
But after compiling I still get

```
# smile
smile: not found
```

Is there another file/header/script where I must add a reference to smile?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what did you do to resolve the issue? How did you generate the executable for smile and move it to /usr/bin?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to specify the directory, or the directory must be part of the `PATH` environment variable.

Try

```
./smile
```

if the program is in the current directory.

or

```
export PATH=".:$PATH"
smile
```

to always check the current directory for commands during this bash session.

If the program is in a subdirectory (eg. `src/commands/smile`) relative to the current directory,
you can add that to the path instead. Either explicitly,

```
src/commands/smile/smile
```

or by adding to the search path

```
export PATH="src/commands/smile:$PATH"
smile
```

Comment: I doesn't change anything :/

Comment: Hmm. Maybe `setenv PATH ".:$PATH"` and `rehash`.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Hmm. `export` should work with bash. This adds the current directory to the search path. I found something that says the default shell is `ash`, but it may be historical. But `export` comes from `sh` and should work on all of them (except `csh`).

Comment: Does the program get compiled in `src/commands`? Maybe you want to `export PATH="src/commands:$PATH"`.

Comment: I think my error is somewhere else. I smile should show up in /usr/bin, but it's not here

Comment: Did you install it? Compiling does not generally install binaries to system locations (for good reason).

Comment: @EtanReisner You sir are completely right! Missed this part >< Thanks

Answer (score 0):

placing your executable in the */usr/bin* folder will allow the shell to recognize it. you should be able to type #smile now